# How to call a bloxplot several times (elegantly)?

Tags: r, boxplot

Sometimes, as in the following code, I call the same boxplot several times.

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:5
r <- boxplot(x, y,col="blue")
grid(nx=NA, ny=NULL) #grid over boxplot
par(new=TRUE)
boxplot(x, y,col="blue")#grid behind boxplot
```

In cases with many boxplot-parameters (unlike here), this generates many lines of code.

How can I use the variable r for the second call in order to save this space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boxplot returns a list which is now in variable `r`.
You can plot it using `bxp(r)`, to get the boxplot again.

For example,

```
bxp(r)
```

As it doesn't store all parameters, one option would be to store them separately... and call them when plotting. In addition to color, I've stored `main` and `cex.axis`

```
lst <- list(z = r, boxfill = "blue", cex.axis = 2, 
        main = "nice title")

do.call("bxp", lst)
```

Comment: I see, thanks. However, the variable r does not contain the information on colours, position of labels etc. So when using "bxp(r)" in a more elaborate example, the two boxplots don't match. Do you know a way to exactly call the same boxplot again without using all the code?

Comment: if you look at `str(r)`, it doesn't store such information.  So, your best bet would be to write a function that wraps the boxplot function. Alternatively, you can use something like `ggplot2`.

Comment: @user3451767 See the new solution. If something like this is good enough, let me know what else you want to pass the boxplot in the `lst`, in case if that was not easy todo.